# Cin.getline() function in if statement

Tags: c++

```
while (true)
{
    cout << "Please enter a  some text: ";
    cin.getline( sendbuf, 100, '\n' );
    i = i + 1;
    if (? = "q") // here i am looking for something that if i press q i should come out of look
    {
        break;
    }
}
```

I am a beginner and eager to learn more. I want to ask if I can provide some way to terminate this loop by typing char 'q' after typing my all desire strings data.

**EDIT** my sendbuf is char* sendbuf, so I don't think so using std::string will help me.

Comment: if (strcmp (sendbuf, "q") == 0)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Don't use a char array, use `std::string` class and you get comparison with `==` for free:

```
#include <string>

std::string line;
while (true) {
    cout << "Enter string: ";
    std::getline(cin, line);
    if (line == "q" || line == "Q") break;
}
```

This way the size of the line is not limited to whatever the size of `sendbuf` is.

If you later need to send data to a function that expects a `char*`, you take the address of the first element (`&line[0]`) or simply call `line.data()`. There's also `size` member function that returns, you guessed it, the size of the string. You're in no way limited by archaic interfaces that work on C-style char arrays. A string **is** a char array, after all.

[Recommened reading: string class documentation.](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string)

Comment: Shouldn't that be `if (line.back() == 'q' || line.back() == 'Q')`? He wants to test the last character after providing input.

Comment: @jrok Thanks but my sendbuf is 'char*senbuf' and i need to store data only in char type buffer due to some processing, so i think   'if (strcmp (sendbuf, "q") == 0)' is fine  as per the requirement. Sorry i didnt mend sendbuf is a buffer!

Answer (score 0):

```
if ( !cin || std::strcmp( sendbuf, "q" ) == 0 ) break;
```

Answer (score 0):

The obvious solution is to use a `std::string`, and put all of
your tests in the `while` condition:

```
std::string line;
while ( std::getline( std::cin, line ) && line != "q" ) {
    //  ...
}
```

In practice, you'll probably want a more complicated test on
`line`, probably factored out into a separate function.
Similarly, if you always want a prompt:

```
std::istream&
getLineWithPrompt( std::istream& source, std::string const& prompt, std::string& line )
{
    std::cout << prompt;
    return std::getline( source, line );
}
```